# Do not get a valid response from API in React-Nodejs project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am building a REST API for my React application in using Express.js.

This is where I call the API from the frontend:

```
const signIn = async () => {
    const user = await fetch(`${SERVER_URI}/users/signup`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email,
        password,
      }),
    })
    console.log(user);
  };
```

On the API:

```
router.post("/users/signup", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let user = new User({
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10),
    });

    await user.save();
    const token = await user.generateAuthToken();
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).send("User could not be created");
    }

    res.status(200).send({ user, token });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});
```

User gets created successfully in the database but when I log the response coming back from the API this is what I see in Chrome:

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:3002/users/signup", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:3002/users/signup"
[[Prototype]]: Response
```

I should be getting the new user object which has just been created along with the token.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you `console.log(user)` and `console.log(token)` before you return your `res.status(200)....` ??? is it returning what you are expecting? the problem might be in those functions

Comment: It is as expected, newly created user object and the token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fetch` function returns a `Response` object. You can use `response.json()` get the object containing your returned data i.e `{ "user": ..., "token": ... }`.

Expected usage:

```
const signIn = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`${SERVER_URI}/users/signup`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email,
            password,
        }),
    });
    console.log(await response.json()); // { "user": ..., "token": ... };
};
```